Normal distribution comparing n variables, are there different solutions?
I am looking for the probability that the variable in year $y_i$ is the largest in a time series. The mean follows a normal distribution $N(μ_i, σ)$ in which $μ_i = α + ßy_i$, $α$ and $ß$ are constants, $y_i$ is the year, and $i = 1, 2, …, n$.
I have found two different solutions in Mathematics to this problem, but for me the solutions seem to give different results.
A)  Bdx77 gave an answer January 18, 2022 to the question: Probability of Maximum from Multiple Normal Distribution. The answer presented a solution with one single product.
B)  Kavi Rama Murthy gave an answer November 18, 2020 to the question: Normal distribution comparing 3 or more variables. The answer presented a solution with the sum of two integrals. I immediately understand the principle in this solution. However, if this solution is used for more than 3 variables, I find that the sum should increase with n! (1, 2, 6, …, n!). For n large (say 100) is it practically impossible to find a solution, quite apart from the difficulty of solving the individual integrals.

Are the two solutions connected in some way?

Is it whatsoever possible to find and solve a theoretical solution for n large (say larger than 100), or do I have to find the solutions by Monte Carlo simulation?


